# how to run asynchronous function synchronously in node js

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am Using Express framework.

The problem I am facing is that I have created a var duration and when a request at '/' is received it simply find the total duration of given video and save to that variable but at the end I want to show that variable but instead of showing that variable value it shows nothing and in console in shows undefined...

can anyone please please help me to tun this code synchronously instead of asynchronous...

thanks alot

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR2Oe.png)

Answer (score 1):

to handle the asynchronous code you need to put

```
console.log(duration);
res.send(duration);
```

inside the callback of `exec`.

modified code:

```
var duration;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    exec('ffprobe -1 ***', function(){
        if(stdout){
            duration = stdout;
            console.log(duration);
            res.send(duration);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but it's worth mentioning that it doesn't "make the code synchronous". It fixes the previously incorrect asynchronous handling.

Comment: thanks for the correction @Robbie - yes!! the code is still asynchronous, now it is just handled correctly. (edited the answer)